# How to get XML text from page using webdriver

Tags: xml, webdriver

I need to read XML file which is displayed in browser.

I have a button XMLVIEWING, when I click on it new window is opened and required xml file is displayed.

So how can I read this file?
I tried getPageSource(), but it returned big String with divs, scripts etc.